# If $CAC'=CA'C'$ for all $C$, then $A$ is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in M_{n \times n}\left(\mathbb R\right)$, and $C\in M_{m\times n}\left(\mathbb R\right)$, $m \ge 2$. If $CAC'$ is symmetric for all matrices $C$ then $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Question body and title don't agree?

Comment: What do you denote $A'$?

Comment: $A'$ denote transpose of the matrix.

Comment: This is odd to say at least. The person who answered did it in 2 mins after the post of such unclear question. If I was trying to answer such question, surely I would have doubts about the meaning of it.

Comment: $A'$ or $A^{T}$ is the usual notation for a transpose. I think $A'$ is not used too much. But still it is recognizable easily that it denotes transpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(It is better if you try to show your efforts first so that people can guide you in the correct destination possibly with some extra hints. This is much more productive. Expressing your thoughts before the community is helpful even if you are wrong)

Since the statement holds **for all $C$**, the idea in the proof is to choose a $C$ which do the job very easily. However, I will follow a very simple idea to prove the same.

***Notation:- For any matrix $P$, $P_{ij}$ denote the $(i,j)$ the entry of $P$***

Then we have, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&CAC'=CA'C'\\
\Rightarrow& (CAC')_{ij}=(CA'C')_{ij}\\
\Rightarrow& \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n C_{il}A_{lk}C_{jk}= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n C_{il}A_{kl}C_{jk}\\
\Rightarrow&   \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n A_{lk} C_{il} C_{jk}= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n A_{kl}  C_{il}C_{jk}\\
\Rightarrow& \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n ( A_{lk}- A_{kl}) C_{il} C_{jk}=0\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Suppose $i \not = j$. Then choose the $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ row of $C$ in such a way that $C_{ip}=C_{jq}=1$ for some  $1\le p,q \le n$, $p \not =q$, and all other entries of both the rows  are zero. It will give you $A_{pq}=A_{qp}$ for that $p$, and $
q$. Do it for all possible $p$ and $q$.